# Change Data Capture for deleted Events

Tags: trigger, event, change-data-capture, lightning-sync-configurations

I created a ticket with Salesforce because outlook attendee event deletion is not firing the trigger or flow. So basically, when these events are deleted from Salesforce there is no way to run any automation.

They suggested `Change Data Capture` as a workaround.
So, I have to catch the event delete action via the `Change Data Capture` trigger. I checked this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_trigger_intro.htm) and looks like we can only do that after insert.

```
trigger EventChangeEventTrigger on EventChangeEvent (after insert) {

}
```

Is it possible to catch the event delete action via the `Change Data Capture` trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger itself is always defined as `after insert`, as it is the *event* that is being created (thus, after insert). The [headers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_eventbus_ChangeEventHeader.htm#apex_eventbus_ChangeEventHeader_changetype) for the event will tell you if it is an insert, update, delete, undelete, etc.

```
for(EventChangeEvent event: Trigger.new) {
  EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = event.ChangeEventHeader;
  String changeType = header.changeType;
  switch on changeType {
    when 'DELETE','GAP_DELETE' {
      // Do something here
    }
  }
}
```